# System does not boot from SSD after re-installation

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd, uefi

I have an ASUS S56CM with UEFI firmware, x64, Windows 8.

- Core i3 processor
- 500 GB HDD (496 GB and 4 GB marked as boot)
- 24 GB SSD (18 GB and 4 GB marked as OEM partition)
- 4 GB RAM

The system used to boot in under two seconds, and the desktop was responsive the next second. Only the HDD used to be visible in Windows Explorer. I installed Windows 8 Professional using Windows OS disc since the Windows 8 that was pre-installed got corrupted.

The first difficulty was that my disk wasn't recognised under UEFI. Rather I booted it under BIOS and I wasn't able to install Windows on any drive. The thing was: Windows under BIOS can't be installed on GPT style drives. I used GParted to convert GPT drives to NTFS drives and installed Windows on my HDD.

Now with Windows on the HDD with 4 GB HDD empty and idle, the SSD with 18+4 partitions are not in use. All my partitions including 4 GB HDD, 1 MB HDD, 18 GB SSD, 4 GB SSD are now visible in Windows Explorer and booting takes 3:27min with desktop responding after 2:26min.

The question is, how do I restore my device to its first state, where it booted within two seconds, while using my SSD?

Answer (score 0):

Restore the OEM Windows8 image and use the [Pro key to upgrade the Core edition to Windows 8 Pro](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/6673-add-features-windows-8-a.html).

Comment: i would need a detailed instructions to bring my device to its original state. I'm a network idiot!! :(

Comment: read the manual of your ASUS S56CM ultrabook. it should explain how to restore it.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't restore the OEM image, as magicandre1981 suggests, you can try wiping the disks and re-installing your Windows 8 Professional in EFI mode. To do this, you'll need to figure out how to control the boot mode of the installer. You can usually do this by hitting F8 or some other function key just after you power on the computer; this will produce a boot menu that enables you to select the boot device. With any luck, you'll see two options for your installation medium, one of which mentions "EFI" or "UEFI" in its description and the other of which doesn't. Selecting the EFI/UEFI option will boot it in that mode and you should be able to install in that mode. Unfortunately, the details of how to get to this boot manager and what options it presents vary from one computer to another, so if you can't find the relevant options, you may need to call tech support or post on a manufacturer-specific forum to get the help you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can't boot Windows 8 in 2 seconds, even on the fastest computer with 4 SSDs in a RAID 0 it would be 10 seconds at least.

Chances are you were in sleep mode and what you saw happening in 2 seconds was the computer waking up from sleep.

Now you've reinstalled, the default behaviour for the power button is shut down, not sleep.

You can change the power button setting back to sleep, and you will see your computer turn on in 2 seconds again.

In any case, Windows 8 is dead, long live Windows 10 :)